# Can you use PollyJS with Node 18 native fetch?

Tags: fetch-api, node-fetch

I've been using PollyJS to record HTTP traffic via [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) and it's working well and as intended.

I'm currently chasing my tail trying to switch this out for Node 18 native/built-in `fetch` which seems to be API compatible.

I'm intentionally not adding the issues to this question because I just want to know if there are any known issues with using Node's native `fetch` with PollyJS? (I can't find any on their issues tracker. But if I were to ask this question there I'm sure I'd be sent here first.)

Answer (score 1):

I also just stumbled across this while upgrading from node v16 with `node-fetch` to node v18.16.0 with native `fetch`. Switching from `@pollyjs/adapter-node-http` to `@pollyjs/adapter-fetch` makes it work for me with node18 (with the PollyJS [Node example](https://netflix.github.io/pollyjs/#/examples?id=node-fetch)), although I do see the deprecation notice: `[Polly] [adapter:fetch] Using the fetch adapter in Node has been deprecated. Please use the node-http adapter instead.` But I couldn't get it to work with `@pollyjs/adapter-node-http`...

Comment: Same for me. Did you find any solution?